# I am trying to write a program that will keep track of a players wins everything works except can anyone tell me why my if statement wont work?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write a program that will keep track of a players wins.

Everything works except can anyone tell me why my `if` statement wont work?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
Private Player1 As String
Private Player2 As String
Private Player1Wins As Integer
Private Player2Wins As Integer
Private Tie As Integer

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub frmMainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Player1 = InputBox("Enter Player 1's Name: ")
    lblPlayer1.Text = (Player1 + "'s Score:")

    Player2 = InputBox("Enter Player 2's Name:")
    lblPlayer2.Text = (Player2 + "'s Score:")


End Sub

Private Sub btnRoll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoll.Click
    ' game of rolling dice

    Dim randGen As New Random
    Dim intNum1 As Integer
    Dim intNum2 As Integer
    Dim intNum3 As Integer
    Dim intNum4 As Integer
    Dim intTotal As Integer
    Dim intTotal2 As Integer

    ' make random integer from 1 through 6
    intNum1 = randGen.Next(1, 7)
    intNum2 = randGen.Next(1, 7)
    intNum3 = randGen.Next(1, 7)
    intNum4 = randGen.Next(1, 7)


    ' display the right image in picDie1
    Select Case intNum1
        Case 1
            picDie1.Image = picOneDot.Image
        Case 2
            picDie1.Image = picTwoDots.Image
        Case 3
            picDie1.Image = picThreeDots.Image
        Case 4
            picDie1.Image = picFourDots.Image
        Case 5
            picDie1.Image = picFiveDots.Image
        Case 6
            picDie1.Image = picSixDots.Image
    End Select

    ' display the right image in picDie2
    Select Case intNum2
        Case 1
            picDie2.Image = picOneDot.Image
        Case 2
            picDie2.Image = picTwoDots.Image
        Case 3
            picDie2.Image = picThreeDots.Image
        Case 4
            picDie2.Image = picFourDots.Image
        Case 5
            picDie2.Image = picFiveDots.Image
        Case 6
            picDie2.Image = picSixDots.Image
    End Select

    ' display the right image in picDie3
    Select Case intNum3
        Case 1
            picDie3.Image = picOneDot.Image
        Case 2
            picDie3.Image = picTwoDots.Image
        Case 3
            picDie3.Image = picThreeDots.Image
        Case 4
            picDie3.Image = picFourDots.Image
        Case 5
            picDie3.Image = picFiveDots.Image
        Case 6
            picDie3.Image = picSixDots.Image
    End Select

    ' display the right image in picDie4
    Select Case intNum4
        Case 1
            picDie4.Image = picOneDot.Image
        Case 2
            picDie4.Image = picTwoDots.Image
        Case 3
            picDie4.Image = picThreeDots.Image
        Case 4
            picDie4.Image = picFourDots.Image
        Case 5
            picDie4.Image = picFiveDots.Image
        Case 6
            picDie4.Image = picSixDots.Image
    End Select
    ' calculate and display total number of dots
    intTotal = intNum1 + intNum2
    lblTotal.Text = intTotal.ToString()

    intTotal2 = intNum3 + intNum4
    lblTotal2.Text = intTotal2.ToString()


    If Player1 > Player2 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Player1 Wins")
        lblWins.Text = CStr(Player1Wins)
        Player1Wins = Player1Wins + 1

        If Player2 > Player1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Player2Wins")
            lblWins2.Text = CStr(Player2Wins)
            Player2Wins = Player2Wins + 1

        Else : MessageBox.Show("Tie")
            lblTies.Text = CStr(Tie)
            Tie = Tie + 1
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to review this *carefully*: [Ask]  Pay particular attention to the part about **Write a title that summarizes the specific problem**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing the NAMES of the two players instead of the values and the comparison for the second player should be an else if for the first if

```
' calculate and display total number of dots
intTotal = intNum1 + intNum2
lblTotal.Text = intTotal.ToString()

intTotal2 = intNum3 + intNum4
lblTotal2.Text = intTotal2.ToString()


If intTotal > intTotal2 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Player1 Wins")
    Player1Wins = Player1Wins + 1
    lblWins.Text = CStr(Player1Wins)
Else If intTotal2 > intTotal1 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Player2Wins")
    Player2Wins = Player2Wins + 1
    lblWins2.Text = CStr(Player2Wins)
Else 
    MessageBox.Show("Tie")
    Tie = Tie + 1
    lblTies.Text = CStr(Tie)
End If
```

And the label update should be after the increment of the counter for wins and ties

Comment: I'll +1 your answer.  Good catch on the wrong value being used in the conditional.   That's what I call going above and beyond.   @karodhill, click the check mark to the left of this answer and also the up arrow.  Thanks and good luck.