# How can i display the last of my code only if the checkbox is checked?

Tags: vb.net

I fixed my syntax,
how can I get the total to show only if checkbox is checked?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Public Class Form1
    Private Player1 As String
    Private Player2 As String
    Private Player1Wins As Integer = 1
    Private Player2Wins As Integer = 1
    Private Tie As Integer = 1

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Player1 = InputBox("Enter Player 1's Name: ")
        lblPlayer1.Text = (Player1 + "'s Score:")

        Player2 = InputBox("Enter Player 2's Name:")
        lblPlayer2.Text = (Player2 + "'s Score:")


    End Sub


    Private Sub btnRoll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRoll.Click
        ' game of rolling dice

        Dim randGen As New Random
        Dim intNum1 As Integer
        Dim intNum2 As Integer
        Dim intNum3 As Integer
        Dim intNum4 As Integer
        Dim intTotal As Integer
        Dim intTotal2 As Integer

        ' make random integer from 1 through 6
        intNum1 = randGen.Next(1, 7)
        intNum2 = randGen.Next(1, 7)
        intNum3 = randGen.Next(1, 7)
        intNum4 = randGen.Next(1, 7)


        ' display the right image in picDie1
        Select Case intNum1
            Case 1
                picDie1.Image = picOneDot.Image
            Case 2
                picDie1.Image = picTwoDots.Image
            Case 3
                picDie1.Image = picThreeDots.Image
            Case 4
                picDie1.Image = picFourDots.Image
            Case 5
                picDie1.Image = picFiveDots.Image
            Case 6
                picDie1.Image = picSixDots.Image
        End Select

        ' display the right image in picDie2
        Select Case intNum2
            Case 1
                picDie2.Image = picOneDot.Image
            Case 2
                picDie2.Image = picTwoDots.Image
            Case 3
                picDie2.Image = picThreeDots.Image
            Case 4
                picDie2.Image = picFourDots.Image
            Case 5
                picDie2.Image = picFiveDots.Image
            Case 6
                picDie2.Image = picSixDots.Image
        End Select

        ' display the right image in picDie3
        Select Case intNum3
            Case 1
                picDie3.Image = picOneDot.Image
            Case 2
                picDie3.Image = picTwoDots.Image
            Case 3
                picDie3.Image = picThreeDots.Image
            Case 4
                picDie3.Image = picFourDots.Image
            Case 5
                picDie3.Image = picFiveDots.Image
            Case 6
                picDie3.Image = picSixDots.Image
        End Select

        ' display the right image in picDie4
        Select Case intNum4
            Case 1
                picDie4.Image = picOneDot.Image
            Case 2
                picDie4.Image = picTwoDots.Image
            Case 3
                picDie4.Image = picThreeDots.Image
            Case 4
                picDie4.Image = picFourDots.Image
            Case 5
                picDie4.Image = picFiveDots.Image
            Case 6
                picDie4.Image = picSixDots.Image
        End Select
        ' calculate and display total number of dots
        intTotal = intNum1 + intNum2
        lblTotal.Text = intTotal.ToString()

        intTotal2 = intNum3 + intNum4
        lblTotal2.Text = intTotal2.ToString()


        If intTotal > intTotal2 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Player1 Wins")
            lblWins.Text = CStr(Player1Wins)
            Player1Wins = Player1Wins + 1
        End If
        If intTotal2 > intTotal Then
            MessageBox.Show("Player2Wins")
            lblWins2.Text = CStr(Player2Wins)
            Player2Wins = Player2Wins + 1
        End If

        If intTotal = intTotal2 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Tie")
            lblTies.Text = CStr(Tie)
            Tie = Tie + 1

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am trying to write a program that will keep track of a players wins everything works except can anyone tell me why my if statement wont work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29110500/i-am-trying-to-write-a-program-that-will-keep-track-of-a-players-wins-everything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you're trying to display the results whether that's a message box or a label but here's how I would do it:

Using a Label/Text Box: Keep it calculating and displaying the total and then put this code on the Changed event of the check box.

```
If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
   lblTotal.Visible = True
Else
   lblTotal.Visible = False
```

If using a message box you would do the same but use MessageBox.Show("Total is: " & MyTotalVariable)